# What's the difference between GTK+ and GTK# and which one is "more multiplatform"?

Tags: .net, user-interface, gtk, gtk#, multiplatform

What's the difference between GTK+ and GTK# and which one is "more multiplatform" ?

Which one is best supported - with the least effort by a mac osx final user ?

Important for me to get out of confusion:

Does .net use gtk# to show forms on non windows platforms ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTK# is .net wrapper for GTK+,

GKT# sharp can run on mono or .net.

.net runs on windows platforms only.

mono is an opensource implementation of .net, it is cross platform and can run on linux, Mac OSX, windows, android and IOS. However the GTK+ is only available on linux, windows and Mac

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) is a great example of a GTK# application which runs on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. On windows it uses .net on Linux and Mac OSX it uses mono.

Because GTK# is a wrapper for GTK+, GTK# can only run on platforms which are supported by GTK+.

However unlike GTK+ program written in c or c++, GTK# applications do not need to be rebuilt for each operating system. So you can deploy the same binaries to all three platforms and run them on either mono or .net.

GTK# applications are more cross platform then GTK+ applications because the same binaries can be run on all three platforms and both runtimes (mono and .net) without needing a recompile.

Answer (score 2):

Gtk# is just a set of bindings for Mono/.NET that allows you to use Gtk+.

.NET does not use GTK#, however, Mono does use Gtk#.  You can use Gtk# with .NET, but .NET does not run on any other platforms.  Mono != .NET, it is close but they are not equal.

Comment: .NET *won't even run* on non-Windows platforms ;-) [Emulators like wine just try to be like Windows, so they are discounted.]